# Tracing the node process executing my script from "npm start"

Tags: strace, node.js

I am attempting to debug a [cli node project](https://github.com/jsdelivr/libgrabber). Its easier to do `npm start` than `npm install -g . && libgrabber`. However, I'd like to run strace on the process. The output of `strace -f` on the `npm start` is much more verbose than the call to node itself. Is there a way to invoke strace from the `npm start` call without all the output from npm itself and just the call to node executing the main script?

Answer (score 2):

Tried [Strongloop's Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) yet?  Basically it uses Chrome's DevTools to debug Node's JavaScript.  Won't help once data leaves Node, but will help you with what I think you're really trying to do; see what is going on 'under the hood'.